# How to switch to TCP version?

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, tcp, udp, network-protocols

I tried to make some customization on this code: https://github.com/c-paras/DistanceVectorProtocol , firstly by changing the type of socket used from UDP to TCP. In this regards, I try it with `socket(AF_INET, STREAM)`. Obviously there are some errors, and I would like to know what are the other lines that should be changed ?

I know that the given protocol is designed exclusively to be used with UDP, my aim is to change it completely.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to add the usual TCP-specific setup calls (like `bind()`, `listen()`, and `accept()` on the server side, and `connect()` on the client side), and you'll also need to add some kind of message-framing logic, since with UDP the networking protocol tracks for you where each UDP packet begins and end, but TCP is a byte-stream protocol so the networking stack won't tell you where the boundary is between one message and the next is; rather you'll need to encode that information into the byte-stream yourself (e.g. with a message-length-header or something) so that the receiver can decode.

Comment: Also note that a TCP connection is inherently one-to-one, it communicates between exactly two endpoints.  If the UDP algorithm expects to communicate between more than two endpoints, you'll need to create a separate TCP connection for each pair of endpoints that need to communicate with each other.